# Density in $\mathbb{Q}^2$

Tags: general-topology

Hello I have a question regarding the following set
$$ E=\{(x,y); x,y \in \mathbb{R}, \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \in \mathbb{Q} \}$$

Is the set dense in $\mathbb{Q}^2$ ? I think yes.

Comment: It’s not a subset of $\Bbb Q^2$; it’s dense in $\Bbb R^2$, however.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott So it is not dense in $\mathbb{Q}^2$ Thank you

Comment: It depends on exactly how you’ve defined *D is dense in A*. If your definition requires $D$ to be a subset of $A$, then it’s false.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Another definition is this: A is dense in a set E if and only if the closure of A equals E

Comment: That definition does imply that $A\subseteq E$; the $E$ of the question is not dense in $\Bbb Q^2$ by that definition.

Comment: Another definition is "$A$ is dense in $E$ if and only if $E \subset \overline{A}$". Then it's dense in $\mathbb{Q}^2$.

Comment: My guess would be $E$ dense in $\mathbb Q^2$ iff the closure of $E\cap\mathbb Q^2$ (relative to $\mathbb Q^2$) is $\mathbb Q^2$. Is this just not standard?

Answer (score 1):

Set $E$ is the rotation of $\mathbb{Q}$ (interpreted as a subset of the real line) around the origin. It is not a subset of $\mathbb{Q}^2$ (for instance, $(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}) \in E$). However, the definition of "dense" may be somewhat loose. The most common ones I've seen are:

$1^{st}$: $D$ is dense in $E$ iff $E\subset\overline{D}$

$2^{nd}$: $D$ is dense in $E$ iff $E = \overline{D}$

$3^{rd}$: $D$ is dense in $E$ iff $\forall x\in E, \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}_{+},\ B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap D \neq \emptyset$

So, by the odd numbered definitions (which are equivalent, by the way), $E$ is dense in $\mathbb{Q}^2$, while, by the second one, it's not.

Comment: The first definition is equivalent to the third.

Comment: Indeed it is, but I was aiming to include the most common definitions and classify set $E$ accordingly (Fixed it, nevertheless).